# How to create this kind of wave gradient effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm attempting to create a similar effect to the one in the image below, however everything from the increasing size, to the smooth gradient across all the objects is proving to be difficult.

I've tried blending and then replacing the spline but the distance was not equal and I couldn't scale the size horizontally. Also, I tried to give each individual object its own gradient as well as tried to make a clipping mask, but both results weren't successful.

I'm relatively new to illustrator and graphic design, so I would really appreciate the insight.[image]

Comment: You probably dont want to use blend for this but rather shapebuilder.

Comment: After blending, I created a wavy line and replaced the spine. Then, I used shape builder to cut off the excess, but the shape became a quadrilateral one rather than staying round.

Comment: No dont do that just make straight lines no shape just open line. Then cut ot in shape and add a stroke profile.

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually my issue was with the stroke profile shape. Would you also happen to know how to achieve the gradient effect as well?

Comment: But you could [use a blend](https://imgur.com/cWpRd4n). I don't see the problem to be honest.

Comment: @BillyKerr, when I attempted to blend, it became this dingy color in the center with solids at the ends. I'm not quite sure how to create what you made. Also, each individual object looks like it has its own gradient, which seems to be another layer of difficulty.

Comment: @BillyKerr, Also, may I ask how you achieved such even spacing with circular shapes? I'm only able to achieve that kind of spacing if I'm using the line segment tool in combination with the replace spine effect. But when I attempt to use ellipses, they end up bunching where the wave dips.

Comment: I didn't replace the spine, I merely edited the existing one to make curves. Also you need to watch the length of the handles as these control the spacing.

Comment: So did you just manually edit everything by eye, including resizing the ellipses?

Comment: The ellipses are all just duplicates, I merely stretched some and squished others. The spine and curves were edited manually, by eye.

Comment: Here's what [the blend looks like](https://imgur.com/JtpOdx8) in outline mode.

Comment: If you don't like the gradient, you could expand the blend, ungroup, convert to a compound path and add a gradient at a slight angle to achieve that look.

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Comment: There is also a tool for making linear object gradients in the edit color menu that allows you to take front object color and back object color and blend betweenn them in the selected objects. Just saying

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a blend.

Here's the blend I made in outline mode. I made one ellipse and duplicated them, stretched some and squished others making sure they were all equidistant. I edited the spine manually to make the curves.  You need to watch the handle lengths as these impact on the spacing of the blend.

[image]

Fill each of the four pieces

[image]

Alternatively, you could Expand the blend, ungroup and convert to a compound path. Then add a gradient at an an angle.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really much different than what other's have posted..

... but I did want to point out that you *can* merely add a **new fill** via the **Appearance Panel** to the **group** created by expanding the Blend and assign the gradient to *that* fill. This allows you to dive into the `Group` and further edit the strokes as *strokes*. Meaning you can change their width or profile more easily.

In other words, you don't *really* need to expand the strokes themselves, just the Blend.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe another way to do it :

I start with some lines with strokes to build it
[image: Strokes]

Then, i select all and go for this pathfinder (you may add stroke and ungroup the result)
[image: Pathfinder]

Delete the unwanted part, chose a stroke profile
[image: stroke profile]

And finally, Outline the strokes to add the gradient

[image: GradientStroke]

The problem with this method is if you need rounded shapes, instead of pointy ones.